# Show select options values on condition in magento 2 admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

I am creating a module where I am listing a custom table, in admin area. I have a status field in the database. What I want is to disable/remove some of the select option from the status field,when user try to edit, based on the condition.

This is my column which shows status:

```
    <column name="Sub_Status" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <options class="vendor\module\Model\Status\Source\Status" />
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
      </column>
```

I tried to manipulate data on the related class `Status.php`

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Model\Status\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;

class Status implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    protected $status;
    //Here you can __construct Model

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $result1 = //has all the db records;
        $currentDate = date("m-d-Y");
        for($i=0;$i<count($result1);$i++){
            $subsOrderDate=$result1[$i]['Subcription_Order_Date'];
            $subsOrderSKU=$result1[$i]['Sub_Sku'];
            $check = 'false';
            if($subsOrderDate<$currentDate){
                $check = 'true';
            }
            switch($check){
                case 'true':                
                    $result[] = ['value' => 4, 'label' => __('Pending')];
                    break;
                case 'false':
                    $result[] = ['value' => 3, 'label' => __('On Hold')];
                    break;
                
                default:
                    $result[] = [
                        ['value' => 0, 'label' => __('Cancelled')],
                        ['value' => 1, 'label' => __('Original Order')],
                        ['value' => 2, 'label' => __('Payment Failed')],
                        ['value' => 3, 'label' => __('On Hold')],
                        ['value' => 4, 'label' => __('Pending')]
                    ];
            }
        }
return $result;
}
}
```

But no luck..How can i achieve this. please help.

Comment: you mean you want conditions to be checked on Edit form page, not on Grid and show all options on grid?sorry, your question is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi It is simple, when admin edit the rows(using inline edit) i want to remove some of the option from the dropdown list. EX- let sayd, if condition matches i want there only one option "cancelled" there, rest of them should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't do that in `toOptionArray()`. Here's what I think should work. Your column in listing UI form:

```
    <column name="column_name" class ="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Grid\Column\ClassName" >
            <settings>
                <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\FreeShippingBar\Source\Status"/>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>select</editorType>
                </editor>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Column Name</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
```

In the class file path given in `<cloumn>` tag on first line:

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ClassName extends Column
{
    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $item='';
                foreach ($items['column_name'] as $status) {
                    if ($status == "pending"/*status value in database*/ && $items['date']==/*getCurrentDate*/) {
                        $item .= "Onhold<br>";
                        $item .= "Cancelled<br>";
                    } elseif ($status == "onhold" && $items['date']==/*getCurrentDate*/) {
                        $item .= "Display<br>";
                    } 
                }
                $items['column_name'] = $item;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Acttually, the conditions I checked maybe not for you but just to get you started that how it works. Whatever you return from here `$dataSource` will be displayed on grid. You can try this and let me know if it does your job.

Comment: great..but can you confirm that this will change the dropdown value not the value coming from the database?? I am confused.

Comment: It will only display on grid, nothing will be changed. For example, if value is `20`, it'll stay `20` but on grid it will show `Display` instead of `20` just to make sense.

Comment: let me make you more clear..Suppose I have 4 status..pending,onhold,success,cancelled. If a user has pending status currently, and the condition matches (which is a date comparison from database date value and current date) i want to show only 2 status to be changed onhold,cancelled.

Comment: I've edited my code, it's a bit messy but you can get the idea. All the conditions you want to check before displaying in grid can be implemented here. I haven't tested the edited part but think it should work or you can ask if it doesn't.

Comment: sure buddy, will let you know once i try this